# Find all of the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My assignment was to find all of the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ so I first found all of the ideals which are:

$\mathbb{Z}_3 \times {0}$, ${0} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$,  $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$,${0} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

I then just modded the whole group by each of the ideals (ignoring the trivial cases). Which told me that

${0} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$, and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ where both maximal and prime.

Is there an easier way to do this by just looking at the structure of the ring? It feels like the way I approached this question was much slower than it should have been.

Comment: Use the Chinese remainder theorem and look for the prime ideals $I$ of the (principal) ring $A=\mathbb Z/ 12\mathbb Z.$ ($|A/I|$ must be a prime factor of $12$.)

Comment: You may find this interesting : [Find all prime ideals and maximal ideals of  Z/12Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625743) and [Describe all prime and maximal ideals of  Zn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569986).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  when you're talking about ideals,  you've got rings, not groups.

Second, in $\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_{12}$, the prime ideals are the prime ideals in $\Bbb Z$ containing $(12)$, by the *correspondence theorem*.

So we get just $(12)\subset(2),(3)\subset \Bbb Z$, which correspond to $(\bar2),(\bar3)\subset \Bbb Z_{12}$.  These are $\{(2,2),(1,0),(0,2),(2,0),(1,2),(0,0)\}, 0×\Bbb Z_4$ (after isomorphism).

So, note:  $\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_2$ is wrong.   It contains $(1,1)$, so any ideal containing it is the whole ring.

You can also tell because the respective quotients, $\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$ are integral domains.

Comment: The whole ring is a trivial ideal of any ring.

Comment: @DougM yes, but by a prime ideal is meant a proper ideal.  Also there was a typo.   I meant $\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_2$, as the OP wrote.